# how to add animate.css class in zoomchart?

Tags: animate.css, zoomcharts

```
 { id: "Japan", coordinates: [139.6503, 37.6762], image: './icons/Location-icon.png' },
```

How to add animate.css class, I try to animate icon.png file. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, ZoomCharts draws the images you give it on an HTML canvas, which means CSS solutions like animate.css won't apply in this case.

I think you'll have to use the ZoomCharts settings to do any styling or animation on the image. See here: https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/api-reference/settings/style/node.html